# Stubbed toe last year still not healed

Tags: injury, sports, soccer, football

While playing football last year(around july/aug) I stubbed my toe against the ground(barefoot). And after a month I got tackled on the same toe(was wearing boots this time). I didn't play much after that(probably just 5-6 times). the pain never went away. While casually paying a few months ago, I stubbed my toe again(it was already in pain). It has been almost a year after the injury the pain has still not relieved. What should I do now? consult a doctor or is it normal? I can still move my toe. But the problems start when I move it too much...I had a similar injury on my thumb few days ago while playing basketball. It has healed within a week. What to do now? I am not able to shoot the ball with my full power now.

Comment: I had this a couple years ago... turned out the muscle on my toe had tightened up from me not moving it enough or something. I had to kinda massage the tension out and the pain went away

Comment: Consult a doctor. My best guess is a detached tendon, which needs to be splinted ASAP.